# What does "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" mean?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am writing a snake game using Pygame in Python3. However, I keep getting this TypeError, not only do I have no idea what it means I have no idea how to fix it

I haven't really attempted anything as I have no idea what it is or how to fix it. This is the code:

```
def draw(self, surface, eyes=False):
    dis = self.w // self.rows
    i = self.pos[0]
    j = self.pos[1]
```

The error message I keep getting is:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "snake.py", line 179, in <module>
main()
File "snake.py", line 175, in main
redrawWindow(win)
File "snake.py", line 127, in redrawWindow
snack.draw(surface)
File "snake.py", line 25, in draw
i = self.pos[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: It means that `self.pos` is `None`, and not a list, tuple or dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs when you try to index through a Nonetype object, e.g.,

```
>>> x = None
>>> x[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    x[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

To properly solve your problem, please post the full code or where you set the initial value of `self.pos`.  It seems that you're setting this variable to `None`.

Comment: def __init__(self,start,dirnx=1,dirny=0, color=(255,0, 0)):
    self.pos = start
    self.dirnx = 1
    self.dirny = 0
    self.color = color

Comment: @j0hn_n4te That actually is still problematic. What is the value of `start`?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an excerpt from the python tutorial by Tech With Tim: https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/game-development-with-python/snake-pygame/tutorial-1/

It is actually caused by a misplaced return inside of the randomSnack while loop.

Full code here: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/jB6k06hG

If the return is inside the while loop (at line 162 in the pastebin) you get this error. I was following the same tutorial and got this error too.

```
# When you call (line 145)
snack.draw(surface)

# you are referencing the snack that was created with (line 193)
snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color=(0,255,0))

# The randomSnack function returns an x and y (line 162)
return (x,y)

# that gets passed into the cube object's "start" parameter (line 12)
def __init__(self,start,dirnx=1,dirny=0,color=(255,0,0)):
```